# Configuring MySQL WordPress settings in wp-config.php for local build and live website

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to edit the MySQL settings for WordPress located in `wp-config.php`. My database name, password, and username is different for the live version of my site and the local version of my site. I am trying to set this up to use one version of the MySQL settings for my local build, localhost, and different settings for the live version of the website, casestudies.splashworldwide.com. What is wrong with what I've done below? How can I accomplish this?

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'case-study-wp');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'casestudies', 'live.domain.url');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'db_casestudies', 'live.domain.url');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password', 'live.domain.url');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'live.domain.url');
```

Comment: PHP's `define()` does not let you define multiple values for a key like you are doing

Comment: @Liz Banach. I have provided with the solution over to the question you have asked. Please refer to that and share thoughts.

Comment: Separate the `define`s in an `if...else` : `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'localhost') { define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); } else { define('DB_HOST', 'remotehost'); }`

Comment: Hi Liz. Sorry to bother you on an unrelated post, but I was wondering why you deleted your more recent question just now. It seemed fine to me and I was thinking of posting an answer. Everything okay there? (I mean, it's fine, and it's none of my business really. I was just curious.)

Comment: Hi @Don'tPanic ! I felt like I was getting some negative feedback and got scared and deleted it :-)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I really wish people wouldn't post "what have you tried" type comments on "how to" questions. If people had tried something that worked, they wouldn't be asking a question. And if they tried something that didn't work, including that would just turn it into a debugging question when it doesn't need to be.

Comment: @Don'tPanic No worries! I did post a FAR more detailed question that hopefully will not get any negative replies if you're interested in taking a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162244/save-value-for-each-acf-repeater-field-row-and-place-all-values-into-one-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This if/else statement worked for me:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'live.domain.url') {
   define('DB_NAME', 'casestudies');
   define('DB_USER', 'db_casestudies');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
   define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
   define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
   define('DB_COLLATE', '');
 }else{
   define('DB_NAME', 'case-study-wp');
   define('DB_USER', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
   define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
   define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
   define('DB_COLLATE', '');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to configure only with one `define` variable in the WordPress and you are overriding the strategy that has been given by WordPress.

> `define()` - If you provide two values for the single define variable as **PHP will never allow you to define two values for single define name** in that manner and it overrides and will only take any one at a time.

Hence it is advisable to add only one configuration per the site and try to change the site credentials when  you go online.

**Keep this alone: For Local**

```
/ ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'case-study-wp');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

**And for Live Site you have this:**

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'casestudies');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'db_casestudies');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Comment: I see. However, my goal is to have only one `wp-config.php` to maintain for the localhost version and the live version in this project's repository. Is this possible with an if/else statement or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable at the top of the page like:

```
$live = false;
```

Then use an if statement to define the credientials like:

```
if($live) {
  define('DB_NAME', 'casestudies');
  define('DB_USER', 'db_casestudies');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
}else{
  define('DB_NAME', 'case-study-wp');
  define('DB_USER', 'root');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
  define('DB_COLLATE', '');
}
```

Then you only have to make one change, changing the value of $live at the top to TRUE when the site goes live.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an Envionment Variable in your local computer to identify it as a development machine (and make sure that environment variable is not set on the production server).

Then inside wp-config.php you can easily check for the existence of the Environment Variable and apply different configurations accordingly:

```
if(getenv('IS_LOCAL')){
   define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
   ....
}else{
   define('DB_HOST, 'mysql.myhost.com');
   ...
}
```

I think this is a cleaner approach than the other answers, because it requires minimal intrusion in the code and allows you to easily debug a production WordPress installation by simply enabling the environment variable also there.