# Save value for each ACF repeater field row and place all values into one array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using WordPress and Advanced Custom Fields to build a website.

I have an Advanced Custom Field repeater field for an event listing on my website. For each event row, there is a sub field to input a date.

I have attempted to save those sub fields into a `$dates` array. However, this `$dates` array is outputting several arrays with only one value with `var_dump()`.

Output of `$dates`:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "June 5, 2018 5:00 pm" }
array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "June 15, 2018 12:00 am" }
array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "July 13, 2018 12:00 am" }
array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "July 13, 2018 12:00 am" }
array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "July 27, 2018 12:00 am" }
array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "August 18, 2018 12:00 am" }
```

With the code below, I am trying to iterate through a `$dates` array and convert the values into a `$month` variable that outputs a month name. The conversion from the date to month name is working, but I need to place these `$month` values for each repeater row into one `$months` array.

I tried to create a `$months` array below and add each `$month` value to that array. This code outputs separate arrays for each repeater row with only one month value in the array. (Same issue as I have with the `$dates` array.)

I'm not sure how to accomplish this or if I am looking at this issue the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php if (have_rows('events')):

while (have_rows('events')) : the_row();

$dates = array();
$dates[] = get_sub_field('date_time');

foreach ($dates as $date) {
  $timestamp = strtotime($date);
  $month = date('F', $timestamp);
  /* this code below does not work as intended */
  $months = array();
  $months[] = $month;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're resetting the months array at every loop. Simply move the assignation outside of your `while` loop.

```
$months = array();

while (have_rows('events')) : the_row();

    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        $timestamp = strtotime($date);
        $month = date('F', $timestamp);
        $months[] = $month;
    }

endwhile;
```

Comment: I think the same

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, and it is still outputting: `array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "June" } array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "June" } array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "July" } array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "July" } array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "July" } array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "August" }`. Separate arrays for each row/value.

Comment: @Liz You want to have the months of each rows grouped as one?

Comment: Yes. I'd like them all grouped into one array.

Comment: @Liz No problem :)